# Dynamically build a resource Identifier

Tags: android

I am tring to get a resource dynamically using

```
 String[] stringarray = res.getStringArray(R.array.XXXX);
```

Where XXXX is a variable.
Any Suggestions?
 Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("the_variable",
    "id", "your.package.name");
String[] stringarray = res.getStringArray(resID);
```