# Getting an array of integers from R.array in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, r.java-file

I want to get the separate arrays from an xml file. The thing is, i need to get those arrays depending on variable i value.

For example: First get R.array.p100, then R.array.p101 ...

```
(int i=100;i<=106;i++)
{
        listaAdy= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        listaOpc = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        String pActual = "r.array.p"+i; // this should get "R.array.p100" but i can't make it work as a parameter.

        int[] arrayAdy = r.getIntArray(pActual);

        for(int j=0;j<arrayAdy.length;j++)
        {
            listaAdy.add(arrayAdy[j]);
        }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically build a resource Identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330231/dynamically-build-a-resource-identifier)

Comment: Solved with that article. Sorry for duplicating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be working:

```
int[]myArray = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.myArrayInXML);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try

 int[] arrayAdy=getResources().getIntArray(getResources().getIdentifier("p100", "array", getPackageName()));
```